# How to make a REST call without redirecting page using angualrjs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, rest, redirect

I have a button link that should call delete on REST api at the backend. But its not working as i expect it to.

```
<li><a href="" ng-click="deleteItem(keyId)">Delete</a></li>
```

Whenever i click this link, the page reloads to http://localhost:3000/item/delete/znEkkLVp

I dont want page reload to happen here. I presume since there is a REST call being made, page reload occurs.

Here is the deleteItem() method:

```
$scope.deleteList = function(keyId) {
    $http.delete('/item/delete/' + keyId);
};
```

How can i prevent the page reload here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use

```
<a href="" ...>
```

as it will reload the page. Instead, use:

```
<li><a href ng-click="deleteItem(keyId)">Delete</a></li>
```

Comment: I didnt knew it would be that simple. Thx